# Why is there extra top margin when using GridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I use GridView in Flutter, there is extra margin at the top, I set the padding and margin to 0 and still the problem persists.

Here is my code:

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, bottom: 0, right: 25, left: 25),
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Text(
            'Let\'s begin',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 2,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
        ),
    GridView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          color: darkModeOn ? Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 50, 1) : Colors.white,
          border: darkModeOn ? Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2) : null,
          boxShadow: darkModeOn
              ? null
              : [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.175),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
        ),
      ),
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          color: darkModeOn ? Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 50, 1) : Colors.white,
          border: darkModeOn ? Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2) : null,
          boxShadow: darkModeOn
              ? null
              : [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.175),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
        ),
      ),
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          color: darkModeOn ? Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 50, 1) : Colors.white,
          border: darkModeOn ? Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2) : null,
          boxShadow: darkModeOn
              ? null
              : [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.175),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
        ),
      ),
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          color: darkModeOn ? Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 50, 1) : Colors.white,
          border: darkModeOn ? Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2) : null,
          boxShadow: darkModeOn
              ? null
              : [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.175),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

I wrapped the above code with ListView. The extra margin on top makes the page look bad. I searched about this problem and found nothing.

The output:

[image]

What I actually want:

[image]

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and run again, from above code I am unable to find any extra spaces while running on web.

Comment: I tried it and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you include you appBar that holding `let's go`. It would be better to observe for me if you include the full widget here.

Comment: The appBar is transparent, and `Let's begin` is not in the appBar

Answer (score 4):

I fixed It! I added

```
padding: EdgeInsets.zero
```

to the GridView